# Check for success on get request in .then() before proceeding

Tags: reactjs, superagent

Using `superagent` in React, I have a function which sends a code to a rest api service. If it succeeds, it sends back a simple `{"success": true}`. What is the best way to check for the successful call before setting the state to another view with `.then(this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE))`

```
acceptPromo (e) {
e.preventDefault()
const { offerId } = this.state
superagent
  .post('/api/user/offers')
  .send({offerId})
  .then(this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE))
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question but you didn't state if the backend responds with error code or with success code, and also what's bad on basic if ? if data.success ..... ?

Comment: @MilosMosovsky - the the backend responds with `success: true` if the submission goes through. I tried `if(data.success) {then(this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE))}`, but get the error that `data` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure for what exactly you are asking but simple if should be enough

```
acceptPromo (e) {
e.preventDefault()
const { offerId } = this.state
superagent
  .post('/api/user/offers')
  .send({offerId})
  .then(data => {
   if (data.success) { 
    this.props.setStep(ACCEPTANCE)
   }
  })
}
```

Comment: I was forgetting `data =>`. Thanks!